# Why am I getting undefined variables in my main SCSS file when variables are imported before other imports?

Tags: css, sass

I'm having an issue with my SCSS imports. I have a base scss file that I am importing all of my other partials into but I'm getting undefined variable errors as a result.

The imports in my main.scss file are organized as follows:

```
@import "variables";
@import "../core/mixins";
@import "../core/typography";
@import "../core/layout";
@import "../core/buttons";
@import "../core/navigation";
@import "../core/forms";
```

In my variables file I am setting global vars to be used throughout the project but when I try to access one of those variables inside my mixins file I get the dreaded "Undefined variable" error.

I feel like this should be achievable without importing the variabbles file into every file that needs to use them if they are all imported, in proper order, inside my main scss file.

What am I doing wrong?

The error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2dnu.png)

And the file tree:
[File Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol92Y.png)

As you can see the variables are imported before the mixins, and the mixins before the other stylesheets that would be using them, but I'm getting the message that no mixin I'm trying to use exists when it clearly does.

I'm also a little confused as to why it would work all of a sudden today and then just stop working again.

I'm using gulp to compile and my tasks are set up to compile the sass in the 'assist' folder which is (supposed to be) importing the core styles.

Comment: From this, you are not doing anything wrong. Can you share with us more information? For example, complete text of the error or a screenshots of your file tree? This is possibly just a typo in your variables file just not the right path for your variables.scss file.

Comment: I thought so. I couldn't figure out what was going on. But after leaving it for the weekend and restarting my machine everything works as I was expecting. Strange, but at least it confirms that I was doing things right. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Ok, not working all of a sudden again. @Sducasse, as per your request I am including screenshots of the error and the file tree.